# Get Android url's content provider of an app

Tags: android, adb, android-contentprovider

I'm testing a Android app which works with Android's content provider: https://github.com/dan7800/VulnerableAndroidAppOracle/blob/master/Vulnerabilities/Content_Providers/Un%20Secure/ContentProviders/app/src/main/java/com/example/hussienalrubaye/contentproviders/MainActivity.java

It stores the data here:

```
String URL = "content://com.example.provider.College/students";
```

Imagine I don't have the source code of this app, is there any way to discover that URL?

I know I can get a lot of info with adb commands, and I've tried

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

to get the package name, but don't know how to get that URL.

Answer (score 2):

Use `adb shell dumpsys package providers` command to list all registered content providers. Then filter by the package name or partial URL